# I have two sets of string,I want get result of combination

Tags: scala, set, combinatorics

I have two sets

```
val set1 = { "A", "B", "C" }
val Set2 = { "all", "all", "all" }

//I want get this result :
result[0]={"A", "B", "C"} 
result[1]={"all", "B", "C"} 
result[2]={"a", "all", "C"}
... 
result[n]={"all", "all", "all"}
```

how can I do this function. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way. You first want to zip the two sequences, because their elements should always align.

```
val seq1 = List("A", "B", "C")
val seq2 = List("all", "all", "all")

val z = seq1 zip seq2 // -> List("A" -> "all", "B" -> "all", "C" -> "all")
```

Then you have to find a way to permutate and assemble (`flatMap`) all the possibilities:

```
def build[A](in: List[(A, A)]): List[List[A]] = in match {
  case Nil => List(Nil)
  case (a, b) :: tail =>
     val tr = build(tail)
     tr.flatMap(xs => List(a :: xs, b :: xs))
}

build(z).foreach(println)

// ->
// List(A, B, C)
// List(all, B, C)
// List(A, all, C)
// List(all, all, C)
// List(A, B, all)
// List(all, B, all)
// List(A, all, all)
// List(all, all, all)
```

Comment: This is output ,It's  not we want `List(a, b, c, all)
List(all, b, c, all)
List(a, all, c, all)
List(all, all, c, all)`

Comment: @lemanli Apologies; I must have posted a wrong version, as I definitely had the correct output; I edited now for the correct version.

Comment: I can admire you, you is very strong. I did another version, but it is complex

Comment: How to close question ,I can' t find what to do